# how to access class variable in static method

Tags: php, static, static-methods

i got error  `Undefined class constant 'app_id'` .I am trying to access the variable declared InitialSetUp class inside `getFBInstance()` method and this method is called from static method `check_user()` .I guess self keyword in this `new Facebook\Facebook([])` refers to the Facebook class thats why the error occurs but how to access the app_id and other variable in `getFBInstance()`

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendorFacebook/autoload.php';
class InitialSetUp{
 public $app_id = "XXXXXXXXXX";
    public $app_secret = "XXXXXXXXXX";
    public $default_graph_version = 'v2.11';

}
public function getFBInstance() {

        return new Facebook\Facebook([
            'app_id' => self::app_id, // here i am not able to access InitialSetUp' app id 
            'app_secret' => self::app_secret,
            'default_graph_version' => self::default_graph_version,
        ]);
    }

    public static function check_user() { 
 $fb = self::getFBInstance();
}
```

Comment: You would need an instance of the class to reference a member.
Make the member static if it does not change values between instances.

Comment: Are you sure those shouldn't be static variables?

Comment: And the proper syntax would then be `self::$app_id`.

Comment: You shouldn't be able to call `getFBInstance()` from a static method, either. It's not a static method, so it has to be called through an instance of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Since `$app_id` is not static you need to instantiate the `IntialSetUp` class. I would also advise you to look into creating [get functions](http://thisinterestsme.com/php-getters-and-setters/).

```
public function getFBInstance() {

    $initialSetup = new InitialSetUp();

    return new Facebook\Facebook([
        'app_id' => $initialSetup->app_id, // here i am not able to access InitialSetUp' app id 
        'app_secret' => $initialSetup->app_secret,
        'default_graph_version' => $initialSetup->default_graph_version,
    ]);
}
```

The `self` keyword refers to elements of the class where it is used and for static properties and methods.

Answer (score 0):

### call variable within class using $this

```
 public function getFBInstance() {

            return new Facebook\Facebook([
              'app_id' => $this->app_id, // here i am not able to access InitialSetUp' app id 
                'app_secret' => $this->app_secret,
                'default_graph_version' => $this->default_graph_version,
     ]);
    }
```